# Meu PHP não salva no BD

Tags: php, html, mysql, banco-de-dados

A conexão com o BD foi estabelecida com sucesso. Se eu jogar a mesma Query no PhpMyAdmmin o comando funciona e os dados são salvos no BD. Porém se eu usar o mesmo comando no PHP ele simplesmente não salva no BD.

Arquivo index.php abaixo:

```
<form action="cadastro.php" method="post" name="signup">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Nome: </label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="nome" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">E-mail: </label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="senha">Senha: </label>
        <input type="password" id="senha" name="senha" />
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit">Cadastrar!</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Arquivo cadastro.php abaixo:

```
<?php 
    //conecta com o banco de dados MySQL
    $DB_HOST = "localhost";
    $DB_USUARIO = "root";
    $BD_SENHA = "";
    $DB_BANCO = "crud";

    $db = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USUARIO, '', $DB_BANCO) or die(mysqli_errno());
?>

<?php
    //resgata o que foi mandado pelo usuario
    $nome = $_POST ['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];

    //funcao para gravar os dados no banco de dados
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user(userNome, userEmail, userSenha) VALUES ($nome, $email, $senha)";

    echo "<h1>CADASTRADO COM SUCESSO</h1>";
?>
```

Eu estava conseguindo aprender bem os conceitos de PHP mas passei o dia todo empacado nessa parte de fazer a conexão entre o código-fonte e o MySQL. Desde já agradeço a ajuda de vocês.

Comment: Aparece algum erro quando é executado? Vendo que você está começando agora, te darei uma dica pra facilitar a descobrir onde é o problema. Use `exit(var_dump($VariavelQueVocêQuerVerOValor))` para parar a execução e te mostrar qual o valor que a variável tem naquele momento. No caso, eu colocaria um `exit(var_dump($sql))` logo abaixo da linha `$sql = "INSERT INTO...` para ver o valor que a variável `$sql` tem, pode ser que não esteja correto essa parte aqui: `VALUES ($nome, $email, $senha)`, talvez não esteja pegando o valor da variavel `$nome` e sim a palavra $nome.

Comment: Nenhum erro aparece ao ser executado.
Usei esse comando que você me passou e aparentemente está tudo rodando normal. Saída: `string(109) "INSERT INTO user(userNome, userEmail, userSenha) VALUES (Allyson Henrique, exemplo@email.com, 1234)"`

Acredito que seja algum problema na conexão entre o banco e o php.

Comment: Estou usando o Navicat para gerenciar meu BD. Quando eu rodo essa Query diretamente no Navicat ele grava no banco de dados. O problema é que a Query não roda no PHP, ou roda mas não grava. Evito perguntar no StackOverflow coisas triviais, mas não consegui achar nenhuma solução para esse meu problema nas minhas pesquisas.

Comment: Copiei o seu código e testei aqui, obtive um resultado positivo e coloquei como resposta. Veja se funciona no seu ambiente e se te atende.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz algumas alterações no seu código para funcionar.

```
<?php 
    //conecta com o banco de dados MySQL
    $DB_HOST = "localhost";
    $DB_USUARIO = "root";
    $DB_SENHA = "";
    $DB_BANCO = "crud";

    $db = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USUARIO, $DB_SENHA, $DB_BANCO) or die(mysqli_errno());

    //resgata o que foi mandado pelo usuario
    $nome = $_POST ['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];


    //funcao para gravar os dados no banco de dados
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO user(userNome, userEmail, userSenha) VALUES ("'.$nome.'", "'.$email.'", "'.$senha.'")';

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    if($result)
        echo "<h1>CADASTRADO COM SUCESSO</h1>";
    else
        echo "<h1>FALHA AO CADASTRAR</h1>";
?>
```

**Alterações:**

1°: Padronizei as variáveis de conexão com o banco. A variável `$DB_SENHA` estava escrita `$BD_SENHA`.

2°: No momento da conexão, você estava passando apenas 2 aspas no lugar da senha, passei a variável `$DB_SENHA`.

3°: Alterei de aspas duplas para aspas simples a `query` SQL. Coloquei pra abrir e fechar com aspas simples e fiz concatenações para pegar os valores das variaveis `$nome, $email e $senha` e ficar com aspas duplas entorno, dado que o MySQL precisa de aspas duplas em um `insert` para ele saber que é um `VARCHAR`.

*Obs: Retorno de um `exit(var_dump($sql))` após minhas alterações:*

`'INSERT INTO user(userNome, userEmail, userSenha) VALUES ("nome", "email@email.com", "senha")'`

4°: Acrescentei o "executador" de SQL, no caso, a linha `$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)`. O primeiro parametro é sua conexão com o banco, o segundo parametro é a `query` SQL.

5°: Coloquei um verificador se deu certo a inserção ou não. O retorno da função `mysqli_query` é `true` ou `false`.

Fiz aqui e funcionou.

Comment: Opa, amigo! Obrigado pela atenção. Consegui rodar o código e gravar no BD usando essa concatenação da forma que você fez!

É uma forma diferente de todas que eu havia visto até então. Consegui aprender bastante com sua ajuda. Obrigado pela motivação e pela atenção!

Answer (score -2):

Está faltando executar a query com o comando `mysql_query`:

```
<?php
     //query de insercao dos dados do tipo string.
     $sql = "INSERT INTO user(userNome, userEmail, userSenha) VALUES ($nome, $email, $senha)";

     //execucao da query e atribuicao do resultado na variavel $result
     $result = mysql_query($sql);

     //verificando se teve algum retorno e mostrando erro
     if (!$result) {
         die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
     }

?>
```

Comment: não fui eu que negativei sua resposta mas o AP usa mysqli então seria ` $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);` e veja também http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Não havia notado, vlw!